# I see that 1>testfile.xml 2>&1 is very different from 1>testfile.xml 2>testfile.xml — but why?

Tags: shell

When I redirect both `STDERR` and `STDOUT` to the same file, it doesn't seem to work, although is it the same as `1>testfile.xml 2>&1`?

**Example:**

```
perl -e 'print "1\n" ; warn "2\n";' 1>testfile.xml 2>testfile.xml
cat testfile.xml
# outputs '1' only.
```

Now, why this confusion? I am actually puzzled... `STDERR` is redirected to testfile.xml and so is `STDOUT`. Why this behaviour? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two redirections are not the same. With what you're doing, both standard output and standard error are redirected to the same file, but with their own independent handles to the file, including the position being written to. Standard error is written unbuffered, and standard output is buffered and flushed when the script ends, overwriting the leading part of what was written to standard error. If your `warn` prints out something longer you can see this:

```
$ perl -e 'print "1" ; warn "foo\n";' 1>testfile.xml 2>testfile.xml
$ cat testfile.xml 
1oo
```

Using `2>&1`, both standard output and standard error refer to the same open file handle/descriptor and they don't overwrite each other.

Comment: I think both `1>testfile.xml` and `2>&1` share the r/w mode and current position and also reference the same open file.

Comment: If the file descriptors are shared will the writes just follow one another or will it be different ?

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution suggested by Shawn results in the command:

```
perl -e 'print "1\n" ; warn "2\n";' 1>testfile.xml 2>&1
cat testfile.xml
```